# How to render an html template with data from view?

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am new to django. I made a form. I want that if the form is filled successfully then django should redirect to a success page showing the name entered in the form but no parameters should be present in the url itself.

I searched on the internet and the solution I got was to redirect to url with pk as a get parameter which fetches the data and shows in the view. But I don't want to pass any thing in the url itself. and some websites say that http can't redirect with post data.

Here's my views.py

```
class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
model = UserForm
template_name = 'userregistration.html'
form_class = UserForm
success_url = 'success'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('success',kwargs = {'name' : self.object.firstName})
```

and here's the template to which I want to redirect:

```
<h2>Congratualations for registering {{name}} </h2>
```

Basically what I want is that if the person fill form mentioning his/her firstName as "xyz" then the redirected success page should say that "Congratulations for registering xyz"

Comment: Your model and your form have the same name?

Comment: I think I see the problem, when you call `get_success_url` method you are redirecting to `success` url, wich must have a view associated, and giving `kwargs` param, you are giving an `url` param to `success` url. I think that is not what you want. How have you defined `success` url?

Comment: I haven't yet defined my success url, but thanks to Deja Vu i got the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django sessions, which I believe installed by default in 1.8

Look [**here**](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html)

```
# Set a session value:
request.session["fav_color"] = "blue"

# Get a session value -- this could be called in a different view,
# or many requests later (or both):
fav_color = request.session["fav_color"]

# Clear an item from the session:
del request.session["fav_color"]
```

You can pass your pk via session and extract your object in another view without affecting your url.
Make sure you clean up after yourself.

Let me know if more help needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways of passing data between views is via sessions. So, in your UserRegistrationView you need to override the form_valid method as shown below.

```
class UserRegsitrationView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.request.session['name'] = self.object.firstName
        return super(UserRegistrationView,self).form_valid(form)



class SuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "success_template.html"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(SuccessView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['name'] = self.request.session.get('name')
        del self.request.session['name']
        return context
```

One more thing that you can modify in your code is that you need not declare `success_url` if you are overriding `get_success_url`